# How to add Google Analytics tracking ID in svelte

Tags: google-analytics, svelte

I want to add my `Google Analytics Tracking ID`- `UA-XXXXXXXXX-X` to my svelte app.

I found two ways of doing it.

First using `Install the global site tag` [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs#install_the_global_site_tag)

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_MEASUREMENT_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){window.dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID');
</script>
```

I think, I have to insert the above code in `app.svelte`. Am I right?

Second, using `@beyonk/svelte-google-analytics`

Installing package using

`npm i --save-dev @beyonk/svelte-google-analytics`

```
import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@beyonk/svelte-google-analytics'

<GoogleAnalytics properties={[ 'google property id A', ...'google property id X' ]} />
```

So where here am I suppose to add `tracking ID`? This is how it is mentioned in svelte documentation [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/e0b826c868aa41379db061c8f63851b7?version=3.35.0)

The `first` or the `second` method to use? This is confusing

Comment: To start with:  UA-XXXXXXXXX-X is a tracking id for [Universal analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10269537?hl=en)

GA_MEASUREMENT_ID is the measurement id for [Google analytics GA4](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10089681?hl=en)

Your mixing systems pick one.

Comment: @DalmTo I am using this for first time. I find first one simple to understand will try to insert it in app.svelte. Could you elaborate what you mean when you say I'm mixing systems?

Comment: beyonk/svelte-google-analytics no longer works for me as of the date of writing the comment. Putting the googletagmanager script right after the header element seems to work fine, however. The Google Analytics docs specifically state that the googletagmanager code must be immediately after the header and before any gtag calls are made.

Answer (score 6):

You can add the global site tag within `public/index.html`. All of your Svelte will be injected into this file, so it will handle all of your pages.

EDIT: SvelteKit 1.0 has this base HTML file as `app.html` in in the root directory, but for whatever flavor of Svelte you're using, just make sure to add it to the HTML file that is hydrated with Svelte.

Answer (score 1):

To insert multiline html into `.svelte` file:

```html
{@html `<!-- google tag analytics goes here -->
<!-- ... -->
<!-- / -->`}
```

or you can insert code into `app.html`

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to add the google code to the app.svelte like this :
1- inside svelte:head </svelte:head>
insert the code with script.

```
<svelte:head>
  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>
  (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','000');
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
</svelte:head>
```

and after the beginning of the body tag or the main tag insert the nonscript code :

```
<main>

<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript>
  <iframe title="gtm" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=0000"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden">
  </iframe>

</noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->

</main>
```

reload your app - which means run npm run build - and upload your files to your server. Check the head tag, the code script tag for google tag manager will be  there in the head and nonscript code will be in the body. You're done.